# PI2/3 Cluster with Hass.io (Home Assistant)

Tags: cluster, docker

I have a `Raspberry PI` Cluster (1 master PI/2, 2 workers PI/3) with `Raspbian`, `Docker`, `Kubernetes` installed. I have no volumes defined (`OpenEBS` seems not officially supported yet).

I initialized helm like this:

```
helm init --tiller-image=jessestuart/tiller:v2.9.1
```

All seems to be nicely configured and working:

```
NAME            STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
k8s-master      Ready    master   5d7h   v1.14.1
k8s-worker-01   Ready    <none>   5d6h   v1.14.1
k8s-worker-02   Ready    <none>   5d6h   v1.14.1
```

Now I need to install Home Assistant:

```
helm install stable/home-assistant --namespace home-assistant
```

Running this command I receive:

```
NAME:   cold-toad
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon May 20 17:51:34 2019
NAMESPACE: home-assistant
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/Service
NAME                      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)   AGE
cold-toad-home-assistant  ClusterIP  10.99.99.120  <none>       8123/TCP  0s

==> v1/Deployment

NAME                      DESIRED  CURRENT  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
cold-toad-home-assistant  1        1        1           0          0s

==> v1/Pod(related)

NAME                                       READY  STATUS   RESTARTS  AGE
cold-toad-home-assistant-745b699cb5-kp985  0/1    Pending  0         0s

==> v1/PersistentVolumeClaim

NAME                      STATUS   VOLUME  CAPACITY  ACCESS MODES  STORAGECLASS  AGE
cold-toad-home-assistant  Pending  0s


NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace home-assistant -l "app=home-assistant,release=cold-toad" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:80
```

But deployment remains in pending.
How can I find the issue?